# How can I move the 3d object and Rotate it 360 displaying on the top of tracking image in Vuforia for android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, vuforia

**How can I move the 3d object and Rotate it 360 displaying on the top of tracking image?** I have used Vuforia SDK for display 3D object on tracking image.

Comment: Could you please provide some more explanation...

Comment: @Sumitsingh i have to display 3D Object on particular image that scan from camera.